# Expressjs routes with named parameters

Tags: node.js, express

Im struggling a bit with named parameters.
Assuming the following:

```
app.get('/names/:name', function (request, response) {
  …
});
```

Is a legitimate route that will response to requests such as `/names/buddy123`

Another legitimate route is:

```
app.get('/names/age', function (request, response) {
  …
});
```

That will response to requests and would probably return a list of all available ages.

Each route is well defined when is defined alone but once both exist, `age` is considered a name and requests arent routed as I'd expect.

Is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to define your `age` route before the named one:

```
app.get('/names/age', function (request, response) {
  …
});

app.get('/names/:name', function (request, response) {
  …
});
```

Comment: I was running 4.13.4 and it is not working for me. Any more ways to test it?